# What Beam Size do I need?

Tags: beam

I am looking to add a hoist to my home shop to lift ±500 pounds. The supports will be 12' apart. What size wood or steel beam do I need? Hoist will be mounted in the middle and not travel.

Comment: I suggest paying an engineer to perform the necessary calculations for safety.

Comment: The consequences in terms of loads and safety mean an engineer should be engaged to make sure.

Comment: If you can't make heads or tails of https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/beams-support-forces-d_1311.html then you need a professional.

Answer (score 1):

A 2x6 will support about 500 lbs. located in the center of the beam spanning 12’ depending on the species and grade.

I used a common grade (No. 1 and Better) of SPF.

I’d use a 4x6 in case of extra load in the future and anchor each end so it does not rotate or move (slide).